# Is uncaught exception message guaranteed

Tags: c++, exception

Is the following code

```cpp
#include <stdexcept>

int main() {
    throw std::runtime_error("foobar");
}
```

guaranteed to produce the following outout?

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::runtime_error'
  what():  foobar
fish: Job 1, './a.out' terminated by signal SIGABRT (Abort)
```

Can I rely on this exact output on every compiler?
Can I rely on that `what` method will be called and error message will be printed will be printed?

Comment: No, that's runtime specific.

Comment: The implementation default handler is free to do what it bloody-well likes, including silently going poof and telling no tale of the aforementioned doom.

Comment: If you want to assure some output then catch the exception. This assures at the same time that the stack is correctly rewinded, which would e.g. include calling the object's constructors.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No it is not guaranteed, it unspecified whether there is any message. From [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/throw):

> If an exception is thrown and not caught, including exceptions that escape the initial function of `std::thread`, the main function, and the constructor or destructor of any static or thread-local objects, then `std::terminate` is called. It is implementation-defined whether any stack unwinding takes place for uncaught exceptions.

The case that is relevant here is "exceptions that escape [...] the main function". The call to `std::terminate` is guaranteed though. And you can install a [`std::terminate_handler`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/terminate_handler) to print a custom message if you like.

Comment: The **output** isn't implementation-defined.

Comment: To expand on Pete's comment, it's not implementation defined; it's unspecified.